# Custom Agenda View in Org Mode: Combining Dates and Tags

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to create a custom agenda in org mode that will show me all the TODO items with a particular tag that are either overdue or due today.

However, I can't find any search function that will allow me to combine the two.  Am I missing something, or am I trying to use the tool incorrectly?

Answer (score 4):

You can use org-agenda-filter-apply. In addition, I found it useful to hide tags in the agenda for current day or week. As the result you have something like that.

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      `(("o" "tasks with tag1"
         ((org-agenda-list)
          (org-agenda-filter-apply ,(list "+tag1")))
         ((org-agenda-remove-tags t)))
        ("d" "tasks with tag2"
         ((org-agenda-list)
          (org-agenda-filter-apply ,(list "+tag2")))
         ((org-agenda-remove-tags t)))
        ))
```

You show tasks with tag1 using Ctrl-a-o and tasks with tag2 using Ctrl-a-d

Comment: In fact, [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361595/emacs-org-mode-agenda-filter-by-owner?rq=1#comment18868850_1361595) would be better applied here : I don't think this code works anymore, but that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve. An update would be very welcome !

Answer (score 2):

The `org-agenda-list` is meant to do this. You can invoke it with `C-c a a`. It displays the agenda for the week, which includes all tasks that are due in the week or are overdue. You can narrow it down to see all tasks scheduled today, due today and all tasks overdue by pressing `d` Further, if you only wish to see tasks with a particular tag, you can do so by pressing `/` and choosing the tag you want to see.

This way you'll get what you want.